# Nvidia drivers on Ubuntu 18.04 USB?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, usb, graphics, 18.04

I have a 128GB Ubuntu (18.04) USB that I have on my keyring so I can take my files, programs, OS, etc. with me to any computer and it works great. One thing that annoys me is screen tearing. The computers I use the flash drive on most do have Nvidia GPUs, but some don't. Would installing Nvidia drivers cause issues while on non-Nvidia PCs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking my answer, I see that my experience was a little out of date,

I now see that Nvidia is smart enough to check if there is a Nvidia graphics card present before loading the driver.

Have not checked with an AMD computer yet.

Alternatively the drive is fairly large, you can dual boot the same OS, but only install Nvidia drivers on one of the installs.

You can choose which install to boot depending on the computers graphics card.

You can share a /home partition between both OS so the only difference in experience between installs is the graphics quality.

Comment: This could be a dumb idea but would there be any way to actually install Nvidia drivers to the internal drive on the computers I want it on, and then just have it revert to the built-in ones if it's not detected?

Comment: @Edia Tech: I  changed my answer. I think it is OK to install the Nvidia drivers, Nvidia is smart enough to check if there is a Nvidia graphics card present before loading the driver. At least that is working for me.

Comment: Ok, I'll install them and tell you if they work on non-Nvidia computers.

Comment: Mine works on a couple of computers with Intel graphics. and it is easy enough to turn off Nvidia if you know you will be using another computer

Comment: Ok, I installed them and it works properly. I tested it on a PC with Nvidia graphics and a laptop with Intel graphics (which I am writing this from) and it works (mostly). Ubuntu has some trouble detecting the display resolution on non-Nvidia devices but it's not that much of an inconvenience considering that I can just go to settings and manually change the resolution from there. Thanks for your help!