# Install ubuntu 18.04 on to usb, for use on multiple pc's, nvidia, intel gpu driver issues

Tags: drivers, system-installation, usb, gpu

What are the options when installing Ubuntu 18.04 onto a usb stick, when the installation is to be run from multiple PC's?

One PC is intel cpu with high end nvidia gpu. Another PC is intel cpu with two nvidia Quadro k2200 gpu's, possible one for display use, the other for math use using cuda or the like. Another laptop is intel cpu but old nvidia quadro fx3600m. These are the specifics, but no need for an answer specific to these. Its the general issue when multiple gpu drivers are needed (and other drivers naturallu..)

Goal here is to have one usb installed that can be used on all these and possible any other PC. Perhaps needed to be gpu optimised at least for one particular pc, and simply able to work on the others.

I have seen some quite complicated ways of doing this. Not interested. Must be easy to do, if not good to know and I'll prefer multiple usb installs.

Comment: Welcome! Ubuntu installers are not customizable (at least not easily). You should install Ubuntu with one USB, and *then* tweak the OS according to your needs.

Comment: So a single usb installed os for each pc?

Comment: You may find this [question and answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/295701/what-would-be-the-differences-between-a-persistent-usb-live-session-and-a-instal/295776#295776) useful.

Comment: Yes. The installer won't give you complex options to suit your hardware, in that regard, the installer is "universal".  You can however, change configuratoins, drivers, etc, once the OS is installed.

Comment: Good, simple is better. One pc - one os install, optimize and done. What about dual gpu's (of the same kind,) does ubuntu handle that well , and will there be a usable option of using one gpu for graphics, and the other for computations (cuda, and more)?

Comment: BTW, if replacing gpu's, is the way to do it to first remove all nvidia drivers, then reboot/replace gpu's, and then reinstall nvidia drivers?

Comment: Assuming that you are doing a Full install to USB, (NVidia drivers do not work on Persistent installs), The last time I checked drivers from Nvidia only work when the computer has Nvidia hardware. If the computer does not have Nvidia hardware the driver has no effect and the drive will boot normally. The drivers are smarter than they used to be. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1084140/nvidia-driver-update-on-ubuntu-18-04-1-live-usb/1084180#1084180

Comment: Another reference: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059732/nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-usb/1059803#1059803